# Azure Function App Blob Trigger, Read CSV Data

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-function-app

I am writing an Azure Function App, currently it triggers when a .csv file is uploaded into blob storage. I am trying to read the data in this .csv file/blob. The following doesn't seem to be working and I am using powershell. Any help or direction is appreciated.

```
#Input parameters are parsed in via param block
param([byte[]] $InputBlob, $TriggerMetadata)

#write out the blob name and size to the information log
Write-Host "Powershell Blob Trigger Function Processed! blob Name: $($TriggerMetadata.Name) Size: $($InputBlob.Length) bytes"

import-csv $InputBlob
foreach( $user in $users)
{
  $UPN = ($users.UserPrincipalName)
  
  write-host $UPN
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
# Input bindings are passed in via param block.
param([byte[]] $InputBlob, $TriggerMetadata)

# Write out the blob name and size to the information log.
Write-Host "PowerShell Blob trigger function Processed blob! Name: $($TriggerMetadata.Name) Size: $($InputBlob.Length) bytes"

$TempFile = New-TemporaryFile
[io.file]::WriteAllBytes($TempFile.FullName, $InputBlob)

$dataSet = Import-Csv $TempFile.FullName

foreach($data in $dataSet){

$data.Username

}
```

This is the data of my .CSV file for testing:

```
Username, Identifier,First name,Last name
booker12,9012,Rachel,Booker
grey07,2070,Laura,Grey
johnson81,4081,Craig,Johnson
jenkins46,9346,Mary,Jenkins
smith79,5079,Jamie,Smith
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Stanley Gong, thanks so much, will try this and let you know :)